# orderBy not working with as keyword laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel and building a query but orderby isn't working with generate fields in select

```
$slots = Slot::select(\DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(slots.when, "%h:%i %p") as timestart,id, `when`, end, namePanel, nameNetwork, nameAngel101, nameAngel102, nameAngel103, locationPanel, locationNetwork, locationAngel101, locationAngel102, locationAngel103, day_id, moderator_id, created_at, updated_at'))->where('day_id',$day['id'])->orderBy('timestart','ASC')->get();
```

the result isn't sorted using timestart, tried printing ->toSql(), it looks fine and runs fine in phpmyadmin

any ideas ?

Comment: What type of error you have seen?

Comment: not an error but the result isn't sorted by timestart at all

Comment: Did you check it by id instead of timestart?

Comment: working with any coloumn except for timestart

Comment: What data type of column timestart ?

Comment: it's a string casted using str to date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201158/discussion-between-abdullah-al-mamun-and-mustafabarakat).

Comment: @mustafabarakat any reasons why you choose to `varchar` because the value *10:00 AM* is actually a `time` column type ref.https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations

Comment: @mustafabarakat by that case you don't need to cast it to date. jsayin :)

Comment: **It can be very helpful if you include your achievements and the goal in your question. So, provide a few initial example records and then explain what the result should be when using your function, as well as the expected correct result.** If there is an example, it's much easier to figure out what you might have done wrong. Right now, there are too many unknowns in the equation, and even the content of the `when` column may not be perfect, even if you claim it to be "in your opinion." If possible, please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

#### STR_TO_DATE

###### Using

`STR_TO_DATE(string, format)`

###### Analyze your format: `%h:%i %p`

`%h`: 00-12 (hour)
`%i`: 00-59 (minute)
`%p`: AM or PM

###### Result

If want a text-based AM/PM display, it will result in an illegal date format, and you will receive NULL as the result.

#### DATE_FORMAT or TIME_FORMAT

###### Using

`DATE_FORMAT(string, format)`

Unlike the previous function, this will return text, but in the desired format: `%h:%i %p`.

###### So what different `01:59 AM` and `01:59 PM`?

If you sort a text character by character in SQL, it will arrange them in the order of each character, so it first checks the first character, then the second, and so on. Based on this, here is an example that gives an illogical sequence:

###### Original

01:59 AM,
03:59 AM,
02:59 AM,
01:59 PM,
03:59 PM,
02:59 PM

###### Result of Order By Asc

01:59 AM,
**01:59 PM**,
02:59 AM,
**02:59 PM**,
03:59 AM,
**03:59 PM**

It is visible that the result is perfect, but logically flawed...

###### Easily Solution 00-23 hour format

If the format doesn't matter, you can use a 00-23 hour format where SQL will perfectly sort the hours.

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(slots.when, "%H:%i")
```

`%h`: 00-23 (hour)
`%i`: 00-59 (minute)

#### Correctly Eloquent Query

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$slots = Slot::select(
    DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(slots.when, "%h:%i %p") as timestart'),
    'id',
    'when',
    'end',
    'namePanel',
    'nameNetwork',
    'nameAngel101',
    'nameAngel102',
    'nameAngel103',
    'locationPanel',
    'locationNetwork',
    'locationAngel101',
    'locationAngel102',
    'locationAngel103',
    'day_id',
    'moderator_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
  )
  ->where('day_id', $day['id'])
  ->orderByRaw('DATE_FORMAT(slots.when, "%H:%i") ASC') // here
  ->get();
```

Since you did not provide a sample of the content in the `when` column, I can only assume that it contains valid dates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this.. I thing it's will help you. Look like below

```
    $slots = Slot::select(\DB::raw('STR_TO_DATE(slots.when, "%h:%i %p") as timestart,id, `when`, end, namePanel, nameNetwork, nameAngel101, nameAngel102, nameAngel103, locationPanel, locationNetwork, locationAngel101, locationAngel102, locationAngel103, day_id, moderator_id, created_at, updated_at'))->orderBy('timestart','ASC')->where('day_id',$day['id'])->get();
```

Comment: that's the same thing